# What is relation between CPT invariance & Lorentz invariance, and why mass of particle/antiparticle is different in CPT violation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, antimatter, cpt-symmetry, cpt-violation

(1) I read that CPT theorem can be proved with Lorentz invariance. Also, CPT violation implies Lorentz violation.

Is CPT invariance equivalent with Lorentz invariance, or just one-side direction holds?

CPT transformation is discrete, in contrast, Lorentz transformation is continuous.
It seems so quite different, but how do they related each other?

(2) In CPT violation case, particle mass and antiparticle mass can be different, like as:

$$ | m_{\phi} -  m_{\bar{\phi}} | \neq 0 $$

I think:

$[ CPT, \hat{H} ] \neq 0$

$ CPT \hat{H} \phi - \hat{H} CPT \phi \neq 0$

$ ( m_{\phi} -  m_{\bar{\phi}} )
CPT \phi \neq 0$

($H = E = \sqrt{m^2 + p^2} \sim m$)

However, such logic also holds for acting only C(charge conjugation). What is the correct explanation for mass difference of particle and antiparticle from CPT violation?

Comment: I read that CPT theorem can be proved with Lorentz invariance. <-- this is not true. Where did you read this?

Comment: I read it from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPT_symmetry   In there, CPT transformation is constructed with assumption of Lorentz invariance.  If this is wrong, then derivation with directly acting CPT on Lagrangian is true? (CPT on free scalar field, or Dirac equation)

Comment: We know CP is violated. That has no connection to Lorentz violation. Should T not be violated by Nature, that’s CPT violation without Lorentz violation

Comment: @YCK39 - Not just Lorentz invariance, you also need a local quantum field theory, a bounded Hermitian Hamiltonian and a unique Lorentz invariant vacuum.

Comment: @Prahar - I don't know why the such conditions are necessary in detail, but I accept them as good ideal conditions for QFT. By the way, how can I show that mass of particle and antiparticle are different in CPT violation?